# Create Inno Setup installer using Jenkins without preinstalling on agents

Tags: jenkins, inno-setup

I want to add Inno Setup to my build, however, the build runs on Jenkins with a lot of agents on different machines.

I would rather that my build was self contained and didn't require me to install items on each agent in order to build it.

Can you run Inno Setup without installing it?
e.g. can I just copy the install directory to a sub-dirrectory of my project and run the `iscc.exe` on the build agent without registering any dlls etc?

Is putting it in the project a bad idea?
e.g. would it be better to zip up the install directory and host it in nexus and download extract it as part of the build?

What are the minimum files I need to run `iscc.exe`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can just copy the Inno Setup installation folder anywhere you want and run it from there. It will just work. [Inno Setup command-line compiler](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline) does not depend on any registry entries or any other external configuration or registration.

You need these files:

- `ISCC.exe`, `ISCmplr.dll`, `ISPP.dll`, `ISPPBuiltins.iss`, `Setup.e32`, `SetupLdr.e32`, `Default.isl`
- `is*.dll`/`is*.exe` for the compression algorithm you are using (the [`Compression` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_compression)); the `islzma*.exe` are used when the [`LZMAUseSeparateProcess`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_lzmauseseparateprocess) is enabled; `zip` and `none` algorithms do not require any dll.
- `WizModern*Image*.bmp`, unless you use your custom images.
- `Languages/*.isl` for the languages/translations you are using.

It does no harm, if you just copy over whole Inno Setup installation folder. Though, there's no point copying the uninstaller files (`unins*.*`).